# How to connect Apple TV (3rd Gen) to the Internet through proxy?

Tags: appletv, proxy

I have an Apple TV 3rd Gen (a1469) running OS 7.2.2.  I need it to connect to the Internet through a proxy.

I've tried downloading AppleConfigurator2 Version 2.7.1 on a Mac with macOS 10.13, but I don't see the Apple TV from AppleConfigurator's interface.

How do I connect the Apple TV (3rd Gen) to the Internet through a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used this particular service but from the looks of it it seems pretty straightforward and easy to setup and configure with a Apple TV. There's a video titled: [Apple TV Setup for Smart DNS Proxy](http://support.smartdnsproxy.com/customer/portal/articles/1352109-apple-tv-setup-for-smart-dns-proxy) on that page that'll guide you through the steps.

Basically what you'll be doing is the following steps:

- Setup an account on [Smart DNS Proxy website](https://www.smartdnsproxy.com/) from a PC
- On your Apple TV go to Settings → General → Network
- Go to Configure DNS and select Manual
- Select an IP for a DNS server from [this page](https://www.smartdnsproxy.com/Servers) that's reasonably close to you
- Reboot your Apple TV

**NOTE:** The [full steps are here](http://support.smartdnsproxy.com/customer/portal/articles/1352109-apple-tv-setup-for-smart-dns-proxy) if you need to change your location etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not trying to only proxy the DNS, but all traffic to the internet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the type of proxy you want to use, do mean a. VPN then? I believe the DNS method will route your traffic as well.

Comment: I have a machine on my network that routes all traffic going through it outside the VPN.  I need all traffic between the appletv and the internet to go through that `host:port`.

Comment: @WalrustheCat - OK makes sense now, thanks. I found this link which shows how to setup AppleConfiguratorv2 which appears to be the only way to do what you want - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89603.

Comment: thanks, but i can't get it to talk to the 3rd gen apple tv.  it is a pretty old model.